# Reading from XML

Tags: jquery

I used this code to get the title on my page from an XML file. Now, I want to display the description for the corresponding titles which is also present in the same XML file. How do I do that?

```
        var queryObj = new Object();
        var querystring = location.search.replace('?', '');
        var vars = querystring.split("&");
        for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) 
        {
            var pair = vars[i].split('=');
            var key = pair[0];
            var value = pair[1]; 
            var value = decodeURI(value);
            queryObj[key] = value;

        }

        if(queryObj["activity"] != "" && queryObj["phase"] != "")
        {
            $("#TaskTitle").html(queryObj['phase']+": "+queryObj['activity']);
        }
```

Comment: if your XML is valid xml, u can use `$.parseXML(string)` instead of parsing it yourself.

Comment: @user2493628 Post the relevant XML here

Comment: <Activities Id="ea1eb36c-f176-40cc-8b06-400ed2af4ff3" Name="Understand Customer Strategies and Priorities" Description="Key Message:\nUnderstanding the stakeholders is one of the critical success factors for any Enterprise Strategy engagement.">
              
        <Task Id="55330fd0-789a-4db4-8625-4125be63107c" Name="Capture Business Drivers, Objectives and Benefits" Description="Work with key stakeholders to identify the top-priority issues. \b Benefits Assessment"></Task>
              <Sequence>2</Sequence>
            </Tasks>
            <Sequence>2</Sequence>
          </Activities>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider I have an XML like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book> ..so on
</catalog>
```

I'd store this in a string, then run [`parseXML()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) over it, which I'd push in a variable like this :

```
var xmlDoc= $.parseXML(myXmlString)
```

I could now this use this `xmlDoc` variable as a DOM object and traverse through it, if needed by passing it to `$()` as an argument.

```
$(xmlDoc)
```

Now, you could read up on `find()`, `closest()` etc and learn up on how you traverse in jQuery.

For example, if i want to get the author of the book **XML developers guide**, which lies in a `<book>` section with id `#bk101`, I'd do this :

```
$(xmlDoc).find("#bk101").find("author") 

             //OR

$(xmlDoc).find("#bk101 author") 

             //OR

$("#bk101", xmlDoc).find("author")
```

That's it. Here's a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/N3mYa/

Answer (score 0):

Try using [jQuery.parseXML()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/), which parses a string into an XML document.